# Drop event javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the div id from the div that I drop the image into. ex I drop it into div 1 i want the text 1 to be printed and same when i drop the image in div 2.

```js
function dragStart(event) {
   event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
}


function allowDrop(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
}

function drop(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.dataTransfer.setData('Text/html', event.target.id);
}
```

```css
.droptarget {
     float: left;
     width: 100px;
     height: 35px;
     margin: 15px;
     padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="img/chip.png" width="30" height="30" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">
</div>

<div id="2" class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.target.id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Just Replace

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ent.dataTransfer.setData('Text/html', event.target.id);
```

To

```
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = event.target.id;
```